# pandas selection by callables

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

**EDIT:** Turns out my initial question was simply a versionitis issue. However, in the course of answering my initial question a few other questions were addressed, so I've reworded the questions and listed them below:

1. I'm familiarizing myself with some pandas capabilities, namely [selection by callables](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-callable). The docs advise use of lambda functions, e.g. to extract all samples in dataframe df1 with value > 0 for feature 'A':

   ```
   df1.loc[lambda df: df.A > 0, :]
   ```

   Is there a more compact, pythonic way to do this?
2. Let's say df1 is now a dataframe with feature A, but the values are mixed doubles and triples (2- and 3-tuples). How can I extract the samples which contain only doubles? I tried doing this as `df1.loc[len(df1.A)>2,:]`, but it's clear that pandas doesn't broadcast the values the way I expect.

Comment: For me it works nice. Maybe restart `anaconda` or other IDE.

Comment: Are you sure about the update? Can you confirm it by typing pd.__version__?

Comment: It works as expected on my machine. I am using pandas 0.18.1.

Comment: Oh how embarrassing! Restarting the the IDE worked. Thanks guys!

Comment: Can you delete the question? TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to restart `IDE`.

Your another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38232452/pandas-selection-keyerror/38232812#comment63886898_38232599):

Use `apply` with `len`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': [(1,2), (1,2), (1,2), (1,2), (1,2,4), (1,2,3)],
        'B': [13, 98, 23, 45, 64, 10]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print (df)
           A   B
0     (1, 2)  13
1     (1, 2)  98
2     (1, 2)  23
3     (1, 2)  45
4  (1, 2, 4)  64
5  (1, 2, 3)  10

print (df[df.A.apply(len) >2])

           A   B
4  (1, 2, 4)  64
5  (1, 2, 3)  10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want to do without the lambda function, as follows:

```
df1.loc[df1.A>0,:]
```

Perhaps the docs are outdated.

Comment: Thanks! Here's a followup question: let's say df1 is now a dataframe with feature A, but the values are mixed doubles and triples (2- and 3-tuples). How can I extract the samples which contain only doubles? I tried doing this as df1.loc[len(df1.A)>2,:], but it's clear that pandas doesn't broadcast the values the way I expect.